# Checking health of all cassandra nodes

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-node-driver

I am writing tests to check metadata information of cassandra keyspace and tables.
I also want to check which node is up or which is down in a cluster. how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nodetool utility gives you access to diagnostic and operational information.

`nodetool ring`

will give you a list of the nodes in the ring and their state.

From the node.js driver you can also get the information. The [Client](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.2/api/class.Client/#hosts) has a `hosts` attribute. Each host has a [isUp](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.2/api/class.Host/#is-up) function you can use. An [example](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/master/examples/metadata/metadata-hosts.js) shows using the metadata:

```
"use strict";
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');

const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'] });
client.connect()
  .then(function () {
    console.log('Connected to cluster with %d host(s): %j', client.hosts.length);
    client.hosts.forEach(function (host) {
      console.log('Host %s v%s on rack %s, dc %s, isUp: %s', host.address, host.cassandraVersion, host.rack, host.datacenter, host.isUp());
    });
    console.log('Shutting down');
    return client.shutdown();
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error('There was an error when connecting', err);
    return client.shutdown();
  });
```

Comment: I have to  write a test for it  using mocha . Is there a module for nodetool or something similar for nodejs?

Comment: something like `const { spawn } = require('child_process'); const ring = spawn('nodetool', ['ring']);` ? its a command line utility.  Ill update above with another mechanism actually too